# why lambda function parameter's type is Nothing on generic type with asterisk in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, lambda

when i call some api, i wished use multiple callback with generic parameter.
so i defined CallBackData class
`class CallBackData<T>(val func: (T?) -> Boolean, val params: T?)`
it not data class. because it super class of other callbacks.

and i define Array<CallBackData<*>> variable for multiple callback.

```kotlin
val callbackDts : Array<CallBackData<*>> = arrayOf(
    CallBackData(::sampleCallback1, SomeClass(1)),
    CallBackData(::sampleCallback2, "hello"),
    CallBackData(::sampleCallback3, -1),
)
```

but when i call func, it say error

```kotlin
Type mismatch.
Required: Nothing?
Found: Any?
```

i don't get it. why? isn't same it.params type T is same of it.func(param(T))? right? why is Nothing Type? why is not same?

this is full code

```kotlin
fun start(){
    val callbackDts : Array<CallBackData<*>> = arrayOf(
        CallBackData(::sampleCallback1, SomeClass(1)),
        CallBackData(::sampleCallback2, "hello"),
        CallBackData(::sampleCallback3, -1),
    )

    callApi(callbackDts)
}

fun callApi(callbacks : Array<CallBackData<*>>){
    callbacks.forEach{
        it.func(it.params)
    }
}


fun sampleCallback1(params: SomeClass?) : Boolean {
    println("sampleCallback1 ${params.toString()}")
    return true
}

fun sampleCallback2(params: String?) : Boolean {
    println("sampleCallback2 $params")
    return true
}

fun sampleCallback3(params: Int?) : Boolean {
    println("sampleCallback3 $params")
    return true
}

data class SomeClass(val i:Int)
class CallBackData<T>(val func : (T?) -> Boolean, val params: T?)
```

i tried convert to like this (using out keyword), but it's failed same.(Lambda's parameter type is Nothing?)

```kotlin
    fun start(){
        val callbackDts : Array<CallBackData<out Any?>> = arrayOf(
            CallBackData(::sampleCallback1, SomeClass(1)),
            CallBackData(::sampleCallback2, "hello"),
            CallBackData(::sampleCallback3, -1),
        )

        callApi(callbackDts)
    }

    fun callApi(callbacks : Array<CallBackData<out Any?>>){
        callbacks.forEach{
            it.func(it.params)
        }
    }


    fun sampleCallback1(params: SomeClass?) : Boolean {
        println("sampleCallback1 ${params.toString()}")
        return true
    }

    fun sampleCallback2(params: String?) : Boolean {
        println("sampleCallback2 $params")
        return true
    }

    fun sampleCallback3(params: Int?) : Boolean {
        println("sampleCallback3 $params")
        return true
    }

    data class SomeClass(val i:Int)
    class CallBackData<T>(val func : (T?) -> Boolean, val params: T?)
```

i look forward to your reply. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the type information of `T` is gone once you projected a `CallbackData<T>` to `CallbackData<*>`. It is no longer known that `it.func` takes the same type as `it.params`.

But you do know that they are the same type in the `CallBackData` class itself, don't you? So you can just add a `call` method

```
class CallBackData<T>(val func : (T?) -> Boolean, var params: T?) {
    fun call() = func(params)
}
```

and

```
callbacks.forEach{
    it.call()
}
```

Or you can overload the `invoke` operator:

```
operator fun invoke() = func(params)
```

You would then be able to do `it()` directly.

Even if you don't have control over `CallBackData`, you can still add an extension function:

```
operator fun <T> CallBackData<T>.invoke() = func(params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function

```
fun <T> CallBackData<T>.call() = func(params)
```

and then `callApi` can be changed to:

```
fun callApi(callbacks : Array<CallBackData<*>>){
    callbacks.forEach{ it.call() }
}
```

Then Kotlin does not have a problem to infer that the types of `func` and `params` match for each `CallBackData`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other answers: if this is the only reason why you defined the `CallBackData`, then you don't really need this class. Kotlin has support for closures, so we don't need to intercept functions and parameters separately:

```kotlin
fun start(){
    val callbackDts = arrayOf<() -> Unit>(
        { sampleCallback1(SomeClass(1)) },
        { sampleCallback2("hello") },
        { sampleCallback3(-1) },
    )

    callApi(callbackDts)
}

fun callApi(callbacks : Array<() -> Unit>){
    callbacks.forEach{
        it()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, consider using lists instead of arrays. In most cases they are just better.